# Component functions of composition of mappings

Tags: real-analysis

Given $\mathbf{F}:\mathcal{O}\to\mathbb{R}^m$ and $\mathbf{G}:\mathcal{U}\to\mathbb{R}^k$ where $\mathcal{O}$ and $\mathcal{U}$ are open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{R}^m$ respectively, and also that $\mathbf{F}(\mathcal{O})$ is contained in $\mathcal{U}$, why is it the case that the composition $\mathbf{G}\circ\mathbf{F}$ can be written as $(G_1\circ\mathbf{F},G_2\circ\mathbf{F},\ldots,G_k\circ\mathbf{F})$, where $\mathbf{G}=(G_1,\ldots,G_k)$?

Comment: I don't think I understand the question. How else do you think it should be written?

Comment: The most obvious way to write it would be $\mathbf{G}\circ\mathbf{F}=((\mathbf{G}\circ\mathbf{F})_1,(\mathbf{G}\circ\mathbf{F})_2,\ldots,(\mathbf{G}\circ\mathbf{F})_k)$.

Comment: The domain of $G$ is $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^m$ whereas $F_i$ maps to $\mathbb{R}$. The composition, as you wrote it would not be well defined.

Comment: Check the edit.

Comment: This is then the same as above. $(G \circ F)_i$ is defined precisely by $\pi_i \circ G \circ F$ where $\pi_i$ is the projection onto the $i$-th coordinate, which is precisely the same as $G_i \circ F$

Comment: Thanks. If you put this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since by definition $G_i \circ F = \pi_i \circ G \circ F = (G \circ F)_i$ for all $i \in \{1, \ldots, k\}$ what you wrote is equivalent to $((G \circ F)_1, (G \circ F)_2, \ldots, (G \circ F)_k)$